# Add an row with searchboxes on UWP DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it possible to add an row with an searchbox foreach column in an UWP DataGrid so I can filter the results by text on that column like in an Excel table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add an row with an searchbox foreach column in an UWP DataGrid so I can filter the results

Currently, there is no such table to make filter directly, and insert new searchbox as a row into `DataGrid` is hard to implement.

For your scenario, we suggest you make `ComboBox` in Top of `DataGrid`, and integrate the property that you want to filter as ComboBox's datasource. Then use the select value to filter your `DataGrid`.

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> temp;
private void SearchBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchBox.ItemsSource = MyClasses.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
    temp = MyClasses;
}  
private void SearchBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Item>(from item in temp
                                                            where item.Name == SearchBox.SelectedValue.ToString()
                                                         select item);
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="SearchBox"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Loaded="SearchBox_Loaded"
    SelectionChanged="SearchBox_SelectionChanged"
     />
```